# TFS Customise Check-In Action on Work Items beyond Resolve or Associate

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, checkin

Can I add an additional option to the linking of work items to a checkin in TFS? TFS has Associate and Resolve, but I would like to have another option to move the work item to a custom state.

Comment: Just rewritten this to try to make this more clearly about work items on check in rather than version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can customize the option on the work items associated with the changeset because it is an enum:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.checkinworkitemaction.aspx

If it's an important scenario for your work you might want to make the suggestion to the TFS team for the next release.

Hope this helps.